# how to retrieve application id of an application in simulator using java?

Tags: java, iphone, automation, appium, appium-ios

How to retrieve application id of an application in simulator using java?

I need this because, i want to navigate to Documents directory of deployed app in Simulator.

e.g
/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<>/data/Containers/Data/Application/78DDB029-1292-4482-992D-F5FBDEAC0DF2/Documents/mylog-2017-02-03T04:23:56.log

I need to programatically  retrieve 78DDB029-1292-4482-992D-F5FBDEAC0DF2.
P.S. I am using Appium 1.5.3 + Java + TestNG

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` it is supposed to give you the PID

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [fbsimctl](https://github.com/facebook/FBSimulatorControl/blob/master/fbsimctl/README.md) command line tool is what you're looking for. It allows you to do various things with simulators, including listing the available ones, getting their status, starting, stopping and installing apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the application ID from the getPackageName() call from a Context object.

When the application ID is changed as part of a build flavour, the package name is replaced with the application ID as the last step in the build process.